How to prevent Chrome (macOS) from removing manually installed extension on Chrome updates?
I’m using 1Password 7 (the very last pre-subscription version) which requires a »classic« (deprecated Manifest 2) extension. As the extension is no longer available through the Chrome Extensions Store, I have to manually install it, by loading the unpacked extension (which I place in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/) via chrome://extensions in Developer mode.
The annoying problem is that with every Chrome update the extension gets removed and has to be reinstalled manually ... and we all know the update frequency of Chrome.
Question is: How to prevent Chrome from deleting the extension?
(Currently using Chrome Version 131.0.6778.109 (Official Build) (arm64) on macOS 15.1.1)

Have you considered using a userscript manager like TamperMonkey?

@Barmar I actually have TamperMonkey running with a couple of off the shelf script, but have absolutely no clue how to write a custom script which would solve the described problem.

Take a look at some of the other scripts, I think you should be able to extrapolate. it's actually easier, since you don't need a manifest. Some of the options in the manifest, like matching the websites, is done in the description file.
